# Replacing column value across tables in a database

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my database which has a common value in different columns in different tables. I want to replace the value with a new value across all the table in the database

For example:

**tbl1:**

```
id    gid        pid

1     local      new
2     remote     old
3     local      local
4     remote      new
```

**tbl2:**

```
id    gid          pid

1     local        new
2     new          old
3     local       local
4     remote      local
```

I want to replace the "local" word with an IP `10.0.0.0` in my all tables in database label.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using php and mysql  As like following ....

```
<?php
     $db = mysql_connect(‘localhost’,’myuser_mydbuser‘,’mypassword‘);
     if(!$db) echo "Cannot connect to the database – incorrect details";

     mysql_select_db(‘myuser_mydbname’); 
     $result=mysql_query(‘show tables’);

     while($tables = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        foreach ($tables as $key => $value) {
           mysql_query("UPDATE $value set pid = '10.0.0.0' WHERE pid = 'local' ");
     }}
     echo "The collation of your database has been successfully changed!";
 ?>
```